# DynamoDB query criteria

Tags: key, amazon-dynamodb

This is a newbie question but I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around DynamoDB concepts.

I have a table with A,B,C & D attributes where A is the hash key and B is the range key. The dao would take in A,B,C values and query dynamoDB to get D value. Have I modeled this right or should I rethink my keys for the query format I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass only the partition key and the range key. In your case you can pass A, B but not C to retrieve D.

In order to pass A,B and C make ABC a concatenated partition key i.e A|B|C
Implement the concatenation at the application layer and pass it to dynamodb